# Jmeter adding variable name instead of variable content

Tags: jmeter, http-post

Jmeter version 3.3. In http post request i am adding parameter. Most of the time ot works but sometimes it does not add variable content but name of that variable. This is how i use my variable:

```
 ${passwordEncFinal}
```

And what i see in request SOMETIMES

```
 password=%24%7BpasswordEncFinal%7D
```

which is metioned

```
 ${passwordEncFinal}
```

I have no explanation for that. Variable should be created before making request.

Comment: How did you create the variable?

Comment: var passwordEncFinal = "xyz";
vars.put("passwordencfinal", passwordEncFinal);

Comment: you should use the key `${passwordencfinal}`

Comment: Its changed ..my first try was to get all to lower case

Answer (score 0):

Rein,

This happens when the variable value is not properly extracted from the response. I would recommend taking following steps in order to resolve this issue:

- Add '[View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)' debugging element in your test and look at the response at the step in your script where you are extracting this variable to confirm if the expected variable value is showing in the response. You can also use [RegExp Tester](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) element in '[View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)' to test your regular expression
- Add Assertion at the step where variable value is extracted to confirm the correct response is returned for the request
- I would also recommend going through the basics of regular expressions using this link: https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/